# Jquery проверить наличие элемента в другому элементе

Tags: jquery

Как сделать чтобы все тэги 
 `<a href="#"><img src="" alt=""></a>`
подписывались классом? То есть как проверить есть ли в тэге a тэг img и назначить ему класс?

Comment: кому  ему? `<a>` или `<img>`?

Comment: в любом случае можно использовать функцию или селектор [`has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно назначить класс всякому элементу `a`, внутри которого есть элемент `img`, то можно сделать это так:

```
$('a img').parent('a').addClass('your_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно добавить родительскому элементу:

```
$('a:has(img)').addClass('your_class')
```

Если вложенному:

```
$('a img').addClass('your_class')
```